# Is it better to use integer or integer array of size 1?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a code written by a colleague. He tried iterating through some values using a for loop, to do so he uses an integer array of size 1.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Call test
End Sub

Sub test()
'my approach
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To 6
       ActiveSheet.Cells(12, x).Value = x
    Next x

'my colleagues approach
    Dim iRCCnt(0) As Integer
    For iRCCnt(0) = 1 To 6
       ActiveSheet.Cells(12, iRCCnt(0)).Value = iRCCnt(0)
   Next iRCCnt(0)
End Sub
```

I assume they are one and the same. Is my approach better or its one and the same?

Comment: Well, both of you could use `Long` for an instance

Comment: For a counter I'd always use the name `i,j,k,l`  and type as @AntiDrondert said would be `long`. For the task in in your example I would not use a loop.

Comment: assuming that the colleague is still in the company and alive you could ask him/her what's the reason :-) TBH, that's the first time i saw such a way to loop a for statement. It's difficult to read.

Comment: From the code provided I have no clue why the colleague is using a one-element array as counter...

Comment: @AntiDrondert okay, i went through some of the other question and realised that integer is converted to long in 32 bit system so its better to use long instead of integer, but that isn't really my question.

Comment: @SNicolaou nope he is no where to be found

Comment: Out of curiosity I ran a timed test on 1 million iterations of each and they both took the same amount of time. So it's really just a matter of preference. Your approach is less confusing for future programmers to read.

Comment: @braX if i had to guess, after compilation the arr(0) and let's say a counter called 'c' would produce a similar lower level code.

Comment: @brax can you add your comment as answer? so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of curiosity I ran a timed test on 1 million iterations of each and they both took the same amount of time. So it's really just a matter of preference.

Your approach is less confusing for future programmers to read, which is an important consideration these days when programmers have to modify each other's code at a later date and the creator of the code is no longer around.

I also tested it using `Long` instead of `Integer` and in this case, it also made no difference. I measured only down to the second tho. Perhaps if you measure down to the millisecond one would be faster... Here's the code I used:

```
Sub test()
  Dim lTmr As Long
  Dim lCol As Long
  Dim dt As Date

  dt = Now

  For lTmr = 1 To 1000000
    For lCol = 1 To 6
       ActiveSheet.Cells(12, lCol).Value = lCol
    Next
  Next

  Debug.Print DateDiff("s", dt, Now)

End Sub
```

Note: I changed the variable names to something a little more meaningful, which is also a good practice for future readability.